# Get page number of pdf form field using php

Tags: php, pdf, setapdf

I am currently using SetaPDF to get the form fields located in a document and saving those form field names in a DB. However, I'm trying to get the page number of those form fields. I can't find anything in the Seta documentation that will help with this. Is there another PDF library I can use to accomplish this?

```
$document = SetaPDF_Core_Document::loadByFilename($file);
$formFiller = new SetaPDF_FormFiller($document);
$fields = $formFiller->getFields();
foreach ($fields->getNames() as $fieldName) {
    $field = $fields->get($fieldName);
    $is_read_only = 0;
    if ($field->isReadOnly()) {
        $is_read_only = 1;
    }

    $is_text = 1;
    $field_name = DB::Scrub($fieldName);

    $base_field_name = $field->getOriginalQualifiedName();

    if (strpos($base_field_name,"#") !== false) {
        $arr_field = explode("#", $base_field_name);
        $base_field_name = $arr_field[0];
    }
    if (strpos($base_field_name,"*") !== false) {
        $is_text = 0;
        $base_field_name = str_replace("*","",$base_field_name);
    }

    $sql = "INSERT INTO [cust].[PDF_Fields] (file_name,field_name,base_field_name,is_read_only,is_text)
        VALUES ('$new_file','$field_name','$base_field_name',$is_read_only,$is_text)";
    DB::Query($sql);
}
```

Comment: If you're iterating over the pages of the PDF, just add a counter and fill the page number with it.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not. I'm opening the document and calling the getFields() method. This gets every field in the document. No page details are included.

Comment: Note that PDF AcroForm Fields are technically not part of any page, and exist as Document wide metadata. Instead Fields are represented on a page by a Widget Annotation. A Field can have zero to many Widgets, which can look different, but all would have the same value.

Comment: Well that's unfortunate. Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: I'm not familiar with SetaPDF but you can try the following (not sure if SetaPDF supports the functionality): from the field object you retrieve the list of field widgets (these are the field representations on the page) and from each field widget you retrieve a reference to the page that contains the widget. This information exists in the PDF file, you have to see if SetaPDF exposes it.

Answer (score 0):

As Ryan already wrote form fields are not directly related to a page but their representations as Widget Annotations are. This is done by adding the reference to the individual Widget Annotations in the `/Annots` array of the page. Sadly it is optional to have this the other way round (from the annotation to the page).

You can get the page and its number through some low level methods of the SetaPDF-Core component: First you need an instance of the Widget Annotation of a form field. This can be done with the [`getAnnotation()`](https://manuals.setasign.com/api-reference/setapdf/c/SetaPDF.FormFiller.Field.AbstractField#method_getAnnotation) method of a form field instance.

Then you can use this instance to search the page via the [`getPageByAnnotation()`](https://manuals.setasign.com/api-reference/setapdf/c/SetaPDF.Core.Document.Catalog.Pages#method_getPageByAnnotation) method of the main pages instance. To get only the page number you can pass this result to the [`getPageNumberByPageObject()`](https://manuals.setasign.com/api-reference/setapdf/c/SetaPDF.Core.Document.Catalog.Pages#method_getPageNumberByPageObject) then.

The written above in code could look like:

```
$pages = $document->getCatalog()->getPages();
$annotation = $field->getAnnotation();
// Method name is a bit vague and accepts an annotation instance starting with revision > 1371 only
$page = $pages->getPageByAnnotation($annotation->getIndirectObject($document));
// $page = $pages->getPageByAnnotation($annotation); // works with revision > 1371
$pageNumber = $pages->getPageNumberByPageObject($page);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I get the following error: Argument 1 passed to SetaPDF_Core_Document_Catalog_Pages::getPageByAnnotation() must be an instance of SetaPDF_Core_Type_IndirectObject, instance of SetaPDF_Core_Document_Page_Annotation_Widget given.

Comment: Sorry, my fault. There was an issue which we'd already solved in our development branch. I updated the code snipped.